# AdMob WindowsPhone 8 same ads all the time

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob

I've integrated AdMob to some of my apps. But I get same ad all the time when I am connected to 3g. And ads are never refreshing. Any idea why is it happening ? Thanks.

Comment: I've got another question. When you just monetize a testing app in AdMob which is not in the store, won't I get the ApplicationId which is required to add in the `<AdControl>`? Yes I do get only the AdUnitId.

Comment: check here ; https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#wp AdUnitID="MY_AD_UNIT_ID" is enough.

Comment: yeah I know, but I thought it works only with Silverlight? Because if you're using `AdControl` through xaml, when you drag and drop, you could see the `ApplicationId` appearing within the tag automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Without making any changes, the `AdControl` includes a property `IsAutoRefreshEnabled` that creates a background timer to refresh ads automatically. This property is set to true by default. The default refresh interval of ads is sixty seconds for the Microsoft AdControl, and for Android it is a server setting in your `AdMob` account. For the windows `AdMob` solution, the refresh interval can be also set in code.

For setting custom Interval you can have Refrence from here [Refresh Intervals](http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-windows-phone-in-app-advertisements)